# How to use C++17 features in an Oct file

Tags: c++, c++17, octave

I'm trying to use `std::optional` (a C++17 feature) in a Oct file for GNU Octave. I have upgraded to g++ version 9.1.0 and set linux environment vars 'CC' and 'CXX' to `/usr/bin/gcc` and `/usr/bin/g++` respectively. Running `getenv` on these variables from within Octave shows that the correct compiler is set. However, when running `mkoctfile', I get the following error:

```
oct_interface.cpp: In function ‘octave_value_list Fmibc(const octave_value_list&, int)’:
oct_interface.cpp:863:10: error: ‘optional’ is not a member of ‘std’
  863 |     std::optional<double> dub_opt = {};
      |          ^~~~~~~~
oct_interface.cpp:863:10: note: ‘std::optional’ is only available from C++17 onwards
oct_interface.cpp:863:19: error: expected primary-expression before ‘double’
  863 |     std::optional<double> dub_opt = {};
      |                   ^~~~~~
warning: mkoctfile: building exited with failure status
```

As pointed out in the comments, the appropriate flag must be passed to the compiler in order to use C++17 features. So, a more precise question might be how to configure `mkoctfile` to pass the `-std=c++17` flag to the compiler.

Comment: Are you building with the flag `-std=c++17`? Sounds like it doesn't think it's building C++17 code

Comment: https://gcc.gnu.org/projects/cxx-status.html#cxx17

Comment: @Human-Compiler yes, that was the problem. Specifically, the option has to be added to the CXXFLAGS variable in Octave, e.g. `setenv("CXXFLAGS", "-std=c++17")`

Comment: It must be set via `set_property(TARGET tgt PROPERTY CXX_STANDARD 17)`, not `setenv("CXXFLAGS", "-std=c++17")`.

Comment: Voted to reopen. This question is a prime example of a question where two different communities / technologies intersect, and neither community by itself knows enough about the question, therefore it invariably gets insta-vote-closed, when in fact it is a very clear question with a very specific, and useful answer. Perhaps we should create a new `octave-dev` tag? In any case,  at this point @S.M. 's answer should be a proper (search-engine searchable) answer to this question, rather than a comment, or Carlton should at least be allowed to answer his own question.

Comment: @S.M. `set_property` is not an Octave command. The correct command is indeed `setenv`.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that the C++17 flag is not being passed to the compiler, as is pointed out in a comment by Human-Compiler. Compiler flags can be passed in two ways: as part of the call to the Oct-file utility, i.e. `mkoctfile -std=c++17`, or by setting an Octave environment variable, i.e. `setenv("CXXFLAGS", "-std=c++17")`